# Valums Ajax Upload with Codeigniter: Get Parameters!

Tags: codeigniter, upload

How do I use paramaters with [Valums Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) and Codeigniter?

Comment: What problems are you having?  What have you tried?

Comment: Haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start.  All I need to pass is an id and a description for the image.  It's a standard upload function that works fine, but I'm not sure how to get it to work if I also need to include a description with the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Valums the parameters are set like so:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    action: '/server-side.upload',
    // additional data to send, name-value pairs
    params: {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2'
    }
});
```

or using

```
uploader.setParams({
   anotherParam: 'value' 
});
```

if you want it to be aware of the state of your app/

```
subD="/Pic"
function selectGaleryName()
{
subD=subD+"/3"
alert(subD) // /Pic/3
}


var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
element: document.getElementById('UploadFile'),
action: 'http://localhost/Farainform/manager/upload.php'
// additional data to send, name-value pairs

onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ 

selectGaleryName();

uploader.setParams({
  subDirectory : subD
});

},


});
```

if you want to set an id and a description for an image you can set these in javascript and then send these. So something like (im using jQuery here):

```
var description = $('#input_description').val(); //This can be an input 
var id = $('#input_description').att('id');

var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    action: '/server-side.upload',
    // additional data to send, name-value pairs
    params: {
        description: description,
        id: id
    }
});
```

Note I havent tested this code and its for demonstration purposes.

Comment: So in my function I don't have to do anything like `function uplodie($params)`??

Comment: I'm more interested in the php part...I got about ^that much from reading it myself...

Comment: All the html/php part is a form for the description underneath the upload button and the php is provided as part of the vallums download, you should just add in something like $_GET['paramName']; to get the param you sent.

Comment: It's not working, Kieran...  Can you please help me out a little bit more?

Comment: I tried using `$_GET['param_name']` and `$this->input->post('param_name')` without success.

Comment: Thats the problem, I forgot. Codeigniter discards any $_GET so if its using that method you will have to change the way the uploader works. Use firebug (firefox plugin) to see what the uploader is trying to do and if there are any errors with the script.

Comment: Bro, I'm at a loss here...totally and completely confused.

Answer (score 2):

$_GET was always destroyed in the 1.7.3 branch but upgrade to the new [CodeIgniter Reactor 2.0](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/downloads) and you'll find that GET strings work out of the box.

When [upgraded](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0), use this syntax:

```
$this->input->get('value1');
```

Comment: Phil! I just read one of your blog posts about upgrading.  I'm running 1.7.3 (I'm also a noob), and I'm really scared of upgrading. Like, real scared.

Comment: Upgrading is easy as hell, but if you are pushed then use 1.7.3. Trouble is, there is no real nice way to enable GET support properly. http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/99570/ parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET) in your controller, but it doesnt always work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it is not documented on Valums page, but apparently parameters should be sent not like this

```
params: {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2'}
```

But like this

```
data: {param1: 'value1',
       param2: 'value2'}
```

On server side you could get them with **$_REQUEST['param1'];**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PHP's input stream in order to obtain the data.

`$fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');`

Then read the data as you normally would with a regular file using `fread()`. Refer to valum's server side code located in server/php.php within the download.

Answer (score 1):

Two related issues that I ran into that might help someone out:

1) var **uploader** causes issues - try using something like **ajaxuploader** instead

2) the documented **setParams** is incorrect for the latest release - it should be **setData**

The end result should be something like this:

```
var ajaxuploader = new AjaxUpload(button, {
        action: 'your-server-script.php', 
        name: 'myfile',
        onSubmit : function(file, ext){

            ajaxuploader.setData({
               somevar : 'somevalue',
               anothervar : 'anothervalue'
            });
)};
```